# Batch pipe to findstr syntax

Tags: batch

I want to find process with title containing some string and pass it's PID to taskkill, but I can't find proper syntax, can somebody tell what is wrong with this line?

```
C:\>cmd /c for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %a in 
('tasklist /v /fo:csv /nh | findstr /r /c:"1234"') do taskkill /f /pid %a
```

Result:

```
FINDSTR: Cannot open do
FINDSTR: Cannot open taskkill
FINDSTR: Cannot open /f
FINDSTR: Cannot open /pid
FINDSTR: Cannot open %a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by escaping the pipe symbol.  To use the `cmd /c` syntax, I had to wrap the whole thing in quotes as well.

```
cmd /c "for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %a in ('tasklist /v /fo:csv /nh ^| findstr /r /c:"1234"') do taskkill /f /pid %a"
```

This [link](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) proved helpful in arriving at the resolution.